@nestjs/axios - Axios Only Returns 502 Errors When Request Fails
I am currently facing an odd problem with Axios (through NestJS HttpService):
I have some Nest endpoints that make HTTP requests to another service. When the HTTP request succeeds, I get a good response from the server and can access the service response and return it to the consumer.
However, when the request fails (for any reason, and the requests ARE making it to the specified service), I always get a 502 ERR_BAD_RESPONSE AxiosError. I have no access to the actual response from the service, just the AxiosError with a 502 code.
Any ideas as to why Axios is not returning the actual response from the service? Thanks!
